# SQL: Filter before or after multiple joins

Tags: sql, postgresql

Will the execution time for these two queries will be the same (or similar)? (Postgresql)

```
SELECT user.id
FROM user
JOIN organization ON organization.id = user.organization_id
JOIN city ON city.id = organization.city_id
JOIN school ON city.id = school.city_id
WHERE school.id = 5
```

vs

```
SELECT user.id
FROM school
WHERE school.id = 5
JOIN city ON city.id = school.city_id
JOIN organization ON city.id = organization.city_id
JOIN user ON organization.id = user.organization_id
```

Comment: Trust the optimizer! Version 1 is the one to use! (Doesn't the second one raise an error?!?)

Comment: _"Will the execution time for these two queries will be the same (or similar)?"_ - (Assuming the second query was actually valid, e.g. by moving the first 3  lines to a CTE) - it's impossible to say without seeing your indexes and query execution plan.

Comment: Check the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html). If you correct the syntax error in the second query, I'm quite sure that you won't see any difference - at least in Postgres

Comment: @jarlh Thanks. Never actually tried the second one (it's more of an theoretical question)

Comment: Oh, and don't forget to ensure your `STATISTICS` objects are up-to-date too - the best index is useless if it has an outdated stats that convince the db engine to do a full table scan....

Comment: Why didn't you try yourself? You would have gotten the answer much faster. https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: @FrankHeikens Didn't have an access to a database, using just an ORM. Also, there were too few data in the database to see an impact.